# What technologies allow bidirectional streaming of video?

Tags: web, video, streaming, flash, javascript

Wikipedia says that Flash allows "bidirectional streaming of audio and video". Is it possible to do that with other technologies (for example with JavaScript)?

In other words, I want to transfer video from one user of web-site to another one in real time.

I want to have something that is already installed by many users or easy to install (Flash fulfills this requirements). And I want to have something free.

Comment: Why not just use Flash?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/) with just JavaScript to have two way communication within browsers. It can even transmit in many-to-many architecture. As flash is almost dead, webrtc is IMHO the future of p2p communication in web.

There are implementations that use webrtc to stream video&audio to make conferences. [Example](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/video-conferencing). There are many other, ready to use solutions like [vline](https://vline.com).

Keep in mind that not all browsers are [well supported](http://iswebrtcreadyyet.com/) - all versions of IE and Safari are lacking native support at the moment, although [third party plugins](https://temasys.atlassian.net/wiki/display/TWPP/WebRTC+Plugins) to close the gap are available.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @mdpc: sure, answer has been rewritten

Answer (score 0):

Flash is probably going to be your best bet since it is already installed for the vast majority of web users and it already supports the technology you're working with (webcams, microphones, audio/video streams, etc.).

Comment: huh? "direct user-to-user connections will be essentially impossible if you're using Flash" what are you saying? flash provides p2p communication for audio and video streams; central server is used only to bootstrap it. this is how [now exploding] number of audio/video chat websites uses it; they do not re-transmit all the streams - that would be overkill; http://newteevee.com/2008/12/04/adobe-makes-p2p-flash-video-available-to-developers/

Comment: I stand corrected on that point.  I wasn't aware Flash had that particular capability.

Comment: please keep in mind that most mobile solutions (phones, tablets) don't support flash.